# download PDF with header and footer with Django

Tags: django, django-views, reportlab

I just started to use Django, and I want to create a button that will initiate a PDF download with a header and a footer. for the PDF I use Reportlab. In the Django documentation, they say to use the Canvas object, but I cannot add a footer and a header with canvas. Can anyone give me a piece of code that will return a response from a view in Django with a PDF download with footer and header?
thank you!

Comment: [`weasyprint`](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/) is a good one to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

Extending `BaseDocTemplate` allows you to define a `Frame` contained within a `PageTemplate`. `Flowables` are used in the frame so your content can flow over to other pages. The header and footer are just strings of text placed on the `Canvas` outside of the frame. `saveState()` and `restoreState()` have to be used when defining a header and footer so that it repeats on each page of your pdf.

```
class HeaderFooterTemplate(BaseDocTemplate):
    def __init__(self, filename, **kwargs):
        self.report_title = kwargs['report_title']
        self.pagesize = kwargs['pagesize']
        BaseDocTemplate.__init__(self, filename, **kwargs)
        main_frame = Frame(
            0, 0, self.pagesize[0], self.pagesize[1], topPadding=25, bottomPadding=18, id='main_frame')
        template = PageTemplate(id='frame', frames=[main_frame], onPage=self.header_footer)
        self.addPageTemplates([template])

    def header_footer(self, canv, doc):
        canv.saveState()
        canv.setPageSize(doc.pagesize)
        canv.setTitle(doc.title)

        # header
        canv.drawCentredString(doc.pagesize[0] / 2, doc.pagesize[1] - 15, self.report_title)

        # footer
        date_printed = 'Date Printed: ' + dateformat.format(timezone.localtime(timezone.now()), 'Y-m-d f A')
        footer_date = canv.beginText(0, 2)
        footer_date.textLine(date_printed)
        canv.drawText(footer_date)

        canv.restoreState()

class PdfTest:
    def __init__(self):
        self.buffer = BytesIO()
        self.pagesize = letter
        self.story = []

    def build_pdf(self, filename):
        """
        Get the value of the BytesIO buffer and write it to the response.
        :param filename: name of the file when downloading
        """
        pdf = self.buffer.getvalue()
        self.buffer.close()

        if pdf:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
            content = 'inline; filename="%s"' % filename
            response['Content-Disposition'] = content
            return response

    def draw(self):
        style = styles["Normal"]
        for i in range(100):
            bogustext = ("This is Paragraph number %s. " % i) *20
            p = Paragraph(bogustext, style)
            self.story.append(p)
            self.story.append(Spacer(1,0.2*inch))

        doc = HeaderFooterTemplate(self.buffer, pagesize=self.pagesize, report_title='Test Header Footer PDF')
        doc.build(self.story)

        return self.build_pdf('test.pdf')

class PdfView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        pdf = PdfTest()
        return pdf.draw()
```

Comment: thank you @bdoubleu, I succeeded creating a pdf and download it, I just could not handle the footer and header. BaseDocTemplate is a document and not canvas. how can I use the document instead of the canvas?

Comment: I've updated my answer showing how to use `BaseDocTemplate`